# Binomial Sum: An In-Depth Analysis into the Relatedness of Two Equivalences

Tags: combinatorics, summation

How is it that
$$n(1+x)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^n C(n,k)kx^{k-1}?$$

How can this be used to show that
$$n2^{n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^nkC(n,k)?$$

Comment: How can this be used? just take $x=1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** We have by the Binomial Theorem:
$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^k.$$
Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$. For the second part, set $x=1$ in the result.

**Remark:** The function $(1+x)^n$ is the **generating function** of the binomial coefficients. One nice thing about the generating functions approach to combinatorial problems is that one can use tools of analysis, in particular differentiation and integration, to obtain combinatorial results. At a more advanced level, one can use *estimates* based on the generating function to obtain bounds on the size of certain combinatorial objects.

Comment: Lovely, the OP should definitely accept this one!

Comment: Not really, your is very nice and more "basic."

Comment: But yours is more aesthetic and pretty straightforward as well.

Answer (score 8):

To obtain the second from the first, just put $x = 1$.

To obtain the first equality, observe that

$$ n(1+x)^{n-1}= n\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}C(n-1,k)x^{k} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}n\frac{(n-1)!}{k!(n-1-k)!}x^{k} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n!}{(k+1)!(n-k-1)!}(k+1)x^{k} = \sum\limits_{l=1}^{n}C(n,l)lx^{l-1}$$

TO observe the last equality, put $l = k+1$.